# Managing Apple/Google inApp Products throught API

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

I have integrated inApp Products into my Google and Apple apps.

I have to visit the corresponding stores to add/edit inApp Products.
Is there any API available to manage(Add/Edit/Delete) inApp Products? So, that i can intergreate the API into my website and mange it easily.

Thanks!

Comment: No you can't do anything like this.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Google Play lets you do this for android. You use the [Inappproducts API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts) part of the [Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/).